# JMH not picking up class to benchmark

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

Having an error whereby JMH is not picking up my class to benchmark.

```
package com.stecurran.jmh.entry;

import org.openjdk.jmh.Main;

public class JmhRunner {

    private static final String TEST = "com.stecurra.benchmark.strategy.EventRunner";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main.main(getArguments(TEST, 5, 5000, 1));
    }

    private static String[] getArguments(String className, int nRuns, int runForMilliseconds, int nThreads) {
        return new String[] { className, "-i", "" + nRuns, "-r", runForMilliseconds + "ms", "-t", "" + nThreads, "-w", "5000ms", "-wi", "3", "-v" };
    }

}
```

Where EventRunner contains:

```
    package com.stecurra.benchmark.strategy;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.GenerateMicroBenchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;



@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class EventRunner {

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void runTest(){

        TimeStore.start = System.nanoTime();


        // FacebookRetriever fbCal = FacebookRetriever.getInstance();
        GoogleRetriever gCal = GoogleRetriever.getInstance();

        CalendarService cs = new CalendarService(gCal);

        for (SimpleEvent simpleEvent : cs.getEvents()) {
            System.out.println(simpleEvent);
        }

        TimeStore.end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(TimeStore.getTime());        

    }

}
```

And I get this error:

Excluding: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod, does not match com.stecurra.benchmark.strategy.EventRunner
No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp? Use -v for verbose output.

How can I change my regex to be valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you actually compiled the project, letting JMH annotation processors to run and generate the benchmark list for you. From the message you have there, it is apparent the `EventRunner.test` had not make it to the benchmark list.

While we are at it, other tidbits:

1. Hijacking the JMH Main might be the easy way into the running the benchmark, but we have better [Java API](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-api-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/) for the use cases like that.
2. Measuring time and especially printing out the time inside for `@GenerateMicroBenchmark` method is not something you want probably. Instead, you need to let JMH to do timing measurements for you. See e.g. [relevant JMH sample](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_02_BenchmarkModes.java).
3. After you eliminate the printout, you will need to feed the values you got into the blackhole, [this the relevant JMH sample](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_09_Blackholes.java).

Comment: Thank you for the clear solutions. Very much appreciated, and keep up the work on this great tool.

Comment: I think you want to update the URLS to point to http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples since the repository format has changed.